# XML not forming as expected in XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I am using following XSLT to form the XML and the code is working fine but I want this code to be wrapped under a condition.

In the following XML since S_HL/D_735='T' appearing only once that's why I dont want the code to be executed.

If G_HL[S_HL/D_735 ='T'] exists more than 1 in the source xml then only the following code should be executed otherwise not required.

**Source XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<M_856>
    <S_ST>
        <D_143>856</D_143>
        <D_329>0001</D_329>
    </S_ST>
    <S_BSN>
        <D_353>00</D_353>
        <D_396>0080000055</D_396>
        <D_373>20240123</D_373>
        <D_337>040849</D_337>
        <D_1005>0001</D_1005>
    </S_BSN>
    <G_HL>
        <S_HL>
            <D_628/>
            <D_734/>
            <D_735>S</D_735>
        </S_HL>
        <S_TD5>
            <D_66>2</D_66>
            <D_67>0BP070A</D_67>
            <D_91>M</D_91>
        </S_TD5>
    </G_HL>
    <G_HL>
        <S_HL>
            <D_628/>
            <D_734/>
            <D_735>O</D_735>
        </S_HL>
    </G_HL>
        <G_HL>
        <S_HL>
            <D_628/>
            <D_734/>
            <D_735>I</D_735>
        </S_HL>
        <S_LIN>
            <D_350>000010</D_350>
            <D_235>BP</D_235>
        </S_LIN>
    </G_HL>
    <G_HL>
        <S_HL>
            <D_628/>
            <D_734/>
            <D_735>I</D_735>
        </S_HL>
        <S_LIN>
            <D_350>000020</D_350>
            <D_235>BP</D_235>
        </S_LIN>
    </G_HL>
    <G_HL>
        <S_HL>
            <D_628/>
            <D_734/>
            <D_735>T</D_735>
        </S_HL>
        <S_PO4>
            <D_82>0.000</D_82>
            <D_350>000010</D_350>
        </S_PO4>
    </G_HL>
     <G_HL>
        <S_HL>
            <D_628/>
            <D_734/>
            <D_735>I</D_735>
        </S_HL>
        <S_LIN>
            <D_350>000030</D_350>
            <D_235>BP</D_235>
        </S_LIN>
    </G_HL>
    <G_HL>
        <S_HL>
            <D_628/>
            <D_734/>
            <D_735>I</D_735>
        </S_HL>
        <S_LIN>
            <D_350>000040</D_350>
            <D_235>BP</D_235>
        </S_LIN>
    </G_HL>
    <S_CTT>
        <D_354>B2B_LIN_COUNTER</D_354>
    </S_CTT>
</M_856>
```

**XSLT 2.0**
Getting stylesheet compilation error now after adding If condition

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <!-- Identity template to copy nodes as-is -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="G_HL[S_HL/D_735='T' and S_PO4/D_350 = following::G_HL[S_HL/D_735='I']/S_LIN/D_350]">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        <xsl:if test="count(//G_HL/S_HL/[D_735='T']) ge 2)">
        <xsl:copy-of select="following::G_HL[S_HL/D_735='I' and S_LIN/D_350 = current()/S_PO4/D_350]"/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Please suggest how to put condition if the G_HL/S_HL/[D_735='T] exists more than once

Comment: `count(//G_HL/S_HL/[D_735='T]) ge 2` is one way to check.

Comment: <xsl:template match="G_HL[S_HL/D_735='T' and S_PO4/D_350 = following::G_HL[S_HL/D_735='I']/S_LIN/D_350]">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
 
<xsl:if test="count(//G_HL/S_HL/[D_735='T]) ge 2)"
    <xsl:copy-of select="following::G_HL[S_HL/D_735='I' and S_LIN/D_350 = current()/S_PO4/D_350]"/>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

Comment: getting error as below for the above XSLT Error: Element type "xsl:if" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>"

Comment: It seems in your snippet in the comment you forgot the close the start tag of `xsl:if` e.g. you need `<xsl:if test="count(//G_HL/S_HL/[D_735='T]) ge 2">`.

Comment: yes , it was missed . now getting compilation with the code

Comment: Stylesheet compilation error

Comment: You insist on introducing syntax errors which were not in the suggested code, the code is `count(//G_HL/S_HL/[D_735='T]) ge 2`, no idea why you add a closing `)` to that and then complain about a compilation error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256659/discussion-between-anird-and-martin-honnen).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure I have understood the complete problem but as we are struggling to interchange code in comments or in the chat I post a working sample:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <!-- Identity template to copy nodes as-is -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="G_HL[S_HL/D_735='T' and S_PO4/D_350 = following::G_HL[S_HL/D_735='I']/S_LIN/D_350]">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        <xsl:if test="count(//G_HL[S_HL/D_735 ='T']) ge 2">
          <xsl:copy-of select="following::G_HL[S_HL/D_735='I' and S_LIN/D_350 = current()/S_PO4/D_350]"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is "working" in terms of counting and in terms of not giving syntax errors, the whole problem is not quite clear so far, as to which part of the input you want to further process or include depending on that count and why you have put further conditions in your code unrelated to the count and not explained in the textual description.